Looking for title of a short story about a girl falling down a well
I remember hearing a story from Grandpa Time clock.
First of all, it’s not Alice in Wonderland.
The girl falls down the well washing something of her mother’s.
She wakes up to find she’s elsewhere. She meets up with an old lady who she helps her with chores around the house.
When it was time for the girl to leave the old lady had precious gems rain down on her.
She goes home and her sister hears the story and goes into the well. She did not help the lady at all and was lazy all the time. When she left the lady had mud (I think) rain down on her.

It sounds like a variant of the Diamonds and Toads fairy tale.

There are many variants of the classic fairy tales, and the version you heard from the Grandpa Time Clock may have been adapted from Diamonds and Toads specifically for the clock. If that's the case the only way to identify it would be to find a catalogue of the original recording used in the clock.

http://www.inthe80s.com/toys/images/user-image-1249691032.jpg

Maybe the name Frau Holle rings a bell. This story from the Brothers Grimm collections is quite similar to the already mentioned Diamonds and Toads, and may have been the inspiration for the story OP heard.

Certainly Frau Holle. Look up the variants in the WP entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frau_Holle#Variants

By the way, Mythology.SE might be the best place to ask about fairy tales. Fantasy has only indirect, if definite, links with myths & folklore.
